# What is the best and simple approach of Kafka microservice upgrade

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, apache-kafka

We have confluent kafka 4.0.0 used in our env as a microservice, we would like to get it upgraded to 5.5.1 version similarly the zookeeper and kafka Rest.
We are running kafka broker and zookeeper as statefulsets and the kafka rest as deployment.

What is the best way of doing this upgrade with rollback procedures on?

> 1. Upgrading the image tag to the version 5.5.1 on the running sts and deployments and change all the configurations under the same
>    namespace.

or

> 2. Creating all the kafka components in a new namespace with upgraded version and new configuration on it and simply route the traffic here
>    by changing the ingress load balancer.

What would be the best way of upgrading out of these methods? also let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're doing the 2nd way:

1. Spin up the new kafka
2. Spin up the new set of workers listening to the new kafka
3. Inject message to test workers-kafka integration
4. Spin up the new app stack feeding the new kafka
5. Inject traffic to test app-kafka-workers integration
6. Switch traffic to the new stack

This is much safer than upgrading live as it lets you verify/debug on all the stages.

Comment: Kafka has very detailed upgrade steps. Are you not changing the log version here?

Comment: I don't even know :) I did both major and minor upgrades in this way

Comment: Well if you spin up new kafka with existing data, but it only is able to read newly formatted log files, it'll fail to start, so are you keeping old data?

Comment: No, we're using it as a queue. I start feeding the new kafka, and just wait until the old one get processed before terminating old workers and kafka.

Comment: I see. Then why kafka instead of an actual message queue?

Comment: Performance, guaranteed processing. In AWS there are not many choices - Kinesis is a pure stream, SQS is low-throughput. So managed kafka it is.